# Python: Header line to use based on my python installation path

Tags: python, web-services, xampp

I am using xampp webserver for running my web service. I have installed python in my "D:\Software\Python34" local drive. My apache server is also running from "D:\Software\Xampp" drive only. So in my python file instead of the line,

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

I tried using the line

```
#!/Software/Python34/python
```

But this throws error in the browser saying ,

```
Server error!

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.

Error message:
couldn't create child process: 720003: test.py

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 500
localhost
Apache/2.4.7 (Win32) OpenSSL/0.9.8y PHP/5.4.25
```

What is the equivalent line for this in my case?

My code is simply,

```
#!python3
print ("Hello World!")
```

Comment: Are you sure it's `D:\Software\Python3.4.2` or is it `D:\Software\Python34` instead?

Comment: I purposefully named it as Python3.4.2. Should i reinstall under the directory name without "." ?

Comment: No, it's just that it's a naming convention used by the Python installation and I thought that might be a issue. Never mind.

Answer (score 0):

Without editing default environment variables in windows, we can just use the following shebang,

```
#!D:\Software\Python27\python
```

to run the piece of python code we have from any web service directory.

Comment: Why `Python27` you're using `Python 3.4.2`?

Comment: because i wanna use xlutil lib which is supported only in 2.7 version as of now.

Comment: So you installed another instance of Python?